# MVC Error Handling with WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller, error-handling

I saw similar post [Error Handling with WCF Service and Client Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578642/error-handling-with-wcf-service-and-client-application) to my question but I needed more help.

I have a MVC project with the WCF Service. I understand that WCF needs to throw a FaultException. But my question is what is the best way to show the error message created by an error in WCF. I just want to redirect all the errors (possibly all FaultException) to one error page (will be generic) but message will be different.

I also would like to use [HandleError] attribute so that I don't have to implement catching FaultException for all the methods calling the WCF service.

Comment: You can create an interceptor that redirect to a specific page if catch a fault exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know how you can handle WCF exceptions but in my opinion this is better to observe these:

1-This not good idea to show user exactly exception message, this is better to show very understandable message for example "Operation get failed there is may problem with back-end service, try again or notify admin"

2- It's is boring end user to redirect to public error page.

3- This is better show the public prompt to user which tell user that the operation get failed exactly where the user do action not redirect it to another page.

4- At the end If you want to do what you want try these:

```
try
        {
            //Call your wcf
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "You message , EXP:{0}...", exp.ToString());
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx?Error=WCfOperationFailed", false); 
        }
```

in your error page page_load:

```
            switch (Request.QueryString["Error"].ToString())
            {
                case "WCfOperationFailed": 
                    litError.Text = string.Format("<h2>Error!.</h2><br/><p>{0}.</p>",GetError());
                    break;
               default:
                break;
}

 public string GetError()
    { 
        Exception lastError = Server.GetLastError();
        return lastError.ToString();
}
```

or you can redirect error message as a `QueryString` to error page and show it to user in `Page_load` like:

```
//in catch block
Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx?Error="+exp.Message, false);
```

in error page `Page_load` :

```
txtError.Text = Request.QueryString["Error"].ToString();
```

However, you can trap errors that occur anywhere in your application by adding code to the Application_Error handler in the Global.asax file:

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

    if (exc is HttpUnhandledException)
    {
        // Pass the error on to the error page.
        Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx?Error="+exc.Message, true);
    }
}
```

This link can be helpful there are some examples
[Error Handling](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling)